# how to used Textwatcher for change of background color of EditText array when we want to guess word of the EditText correctly

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

How do I use `Textwatcher` for change of the background color of an `EditText` array when we want to guess the word of the `EditText` correctly?

example:

```
public EditText[] edts=new EditText[9];
String[] etd={"f","m","v","f","m","v","f","m","v"};
```

Comment: Some clarity improvements.

Comment: Dear Tripp Kinetics thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `onTextChangedListener` to all of your EditTexts:

```
    public EditText[] edts=new EditText[9];
    String[] etd={"f","m","v","f","m","v","f","m","v"};
    private void addTextChangedListeners() {
        for (int i = 0; i < edts.length; i++) {
            final int idx = i; //necessary for inner class
            edts[i].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    //No implementation needed.
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if (s.toString().equals(etd[idx])) {
                        edts[idx].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF"));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    //No implementation needed.
                }
            });
        }
    }
```